# Main method not printing the number to be returned

Tags: java

I was trying to have my main method call on a non static array method. After calculating the minimum gap, that number is to be returned and printed by the main method, but nothing is happening after I enter the numbers for the array. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```
public class Lab1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("How many elements would you like the array to have?");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int arraySize = input.nextInt();
        int value[] = new int[arraySize];

        System.out.println("Enter numbers for the array.");
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            value[i] = input.nextInt();
            Lab1 lab1 = new Lab1();
            lab1.minGap(value);
        }
    }

    public int minGap(int[] value) {
        if (value.length < 2)
            return 0;
        int minGap = value[1] - value[0];
        for (int i = 2; i < value.length; i++) {
            int gap = value[i] - value[i - 1];
            if (gap < minGap)
                minGap = gap;
        }
        return minGap;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are never printing the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You called the method for calculating the minimum number inside the for loop. But you will need the value returned by it. You will have to call that method and then print out the value returned by
  that method.
- Also you need to initialize the object outside the for loop.

This is how your main method code should look like :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("How many elements would you like the array to have?");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arraySize = input.nextInt();
    int value[] = new int[arraySize];

    System.out.println("Enter numbers for the array.");
    Lab1 lab1 = new Lab1();
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        value[i] = input.nextInt();   
    }
    System.out.println(lab1.minGap(value));
}
```

Comment: You should explain what you've changed, so OP can understand what she did wrong.

Comment: Added the explanation

Comment: *"You never called the method for calculating the minimum number."* She does (but yes, she ignores the result). Btw I'm not the one who downvotes here.

Comment: Edited my explanation. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanation alongside the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You are not ever printing your value. Output it to the console or application. It is returning but it does not become visible to end user unless you output it in some way.

```
System.out.println(ReturnedVal);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where did you get `ReturnedVal` ? And only that would not fix the code. I did not downvote you though.

Comment: For him to replace with there var. Could have made that more clear